# Gnuplot: logscale y moves x axis labels and inverts y axis when using view map

Tags: gnuplot, heatmap, axis-labels

I stumbled across some behavior in Gnuplot 5.2 patchlevel 2, and I can't find if it's a bug or a feature:
I want to plot a heat map, but when I set the y axis to logscale the axis inverts and all labels of the x axis are moved to the upper part of the plot with the xlabel inside the plot. Also the the y axis gets inverted. If instead I only set logscale x then nothing unexpected happens. This seems to be linked to "set view map". If I omit this line then it works as expected (just not as needed).

Does anyone know what might be the problem?

EDIT: Turns out, this is a bug in 5.2.2 . It doesn't happen in later versions anymore.

```
set terminal "pdfcairo" enhanced dashed size 10,5

set termoptions font "Helvetica,15"

set palette defined (-3 "#1E90FF", 1 "#FFFACD", 4 "#CD5C5C")

set view map
set xlabel "x"
set ylabel "y"
set cblabel "x*y"


set output "table.pdf"
set multiplot
    set size .45,1.0
    set origin .0,.0
    splot 'table.dat' using 1:2:3 with pm3d notitle
    
    set logscale y
    set size .45,1.0
    set origin .5,.0
    
    replot
    
unset multiplot
unset output

exit
```

[image: Output of the example]

Comment: Probably, seems to be a gnuplot <=5.2.2 specific problem. I don't see this in gnuplot >=5.2.3

Comment: @theozh You seem to be right. I'm now at the office with access to a newer machine with 5.2.8 and there it also doesn't happen. Thx